# How to use Twitter Boootstrap's form validation tooltip messages?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

First of all, I am not asking about using Bootstrap's javascript guide to write tooltips from scratch which is [in the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

I recently used `type="email"`, along with `v3.3.1`. It automatically validated and showed **awesome tooltips** for wrong `email`. I am looking to extend this to custom fields (`type="text"` and so on) with least amount of code. Looking at Bootstrap's docs, I didn't find any such documentation.

I am wondering it I can use something that resembles [formvalidation.io](http://formvalidation.io/examples/changing-tooltip-position/) for validation without writing a ton of javascript combined with above tooltip style.

I can do javascript, but if there's a better way, I would like to know.

Right now, my `form` is extremely simple, no tooltip Javascript and this works:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
    <!--<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ CSRF_TOKEN }}">-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="data.email" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="data.password" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change/edit the message of the tooltip  using `pattern`

```
 <input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"
    oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Enter a letter from the english alphabet ')"
    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" />
```

[Good Link on patterns right here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#form.data.pattern): it has time and a lot of data types patterns

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. **Regex** is cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use type="email" the tooltips you see are generated by the browser.

Comment: Yeah, realized this after you mentioned it!